# Overwrite an import in an imported package

Tags: python, import, dependencies, package

Here is my situation:

My code does:

```py
from verbose import Classy

c = Classy(False)
```

And it fails, because there is an error in `verbose`, which looks like this:

```py
from deep import deepa, deepb, deepc, deepd

class Classy:
  def __init__(self, arg):
    if arg:
      self.x = deepa
      self.y = deepb
    else:
      self.x = deepc
      self.y = deepd
```

And that is right, otherwise I could submit a pull request, but it is right. The problem is: the world is not prepared, and it fails. I need to patch it with a workaround, and I would need it to read as:

```py
from deep import deepa, deepb, deepc, deepd

class Classy:
  def __init__(self, arg):
    if arg:
      self.x = deepa
      self.y = deepb
    else:
      self.x = deepc
      self.y = deepb
```

The difference is in the last line. It is subtle.

So far, I am just copying and pasting the code from `verbose`, and just using a class that is different in that one single line, problem is: it is verbose, so it is actually 500 lines.

I would like in the code before importing `verbose` to somehow overwrite the reference to `deepd` (failing by being ahead of its time) with a reference to `deepb` which works just fine.

Comment: I understand that bottom up this would raise security alarms, but top down it should not IMHO, I already have a code that works, I am just looking for a way to replace 500 lines with two or three.

Comment: Can't you just add something like `from deep import deepb; sys.modules['deep.deepd'] = deepb` after importing `Classy`?